# Enviar datos al controlador a travez de vue, axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

hola necesito enviar datos desde frontend de un formulario hacia un controlador que realiza una busqueda, por medio de uno o mas datos de los textbox que se encuentran en dicho formulario(nombre, apellido, telefono, idcontrato, etc) este es mi frontend: index.vue:

```
export default {
    data()
    {
        return 
        {
           form: 
             {
              firstname: null,
              lastname: null,
              DNI: null,
              birthday:null,
              cdcontract:null,
              domicile:null,
              cellphone:null
            }
        }
    }
    methods: {
        ...mapActions({
          fetchContracts: "contract/fetchContracts"
        }),
        fetchContractsWrapper() {
          this.loading = true;
          this.fetchContracts(this.form).finally(() => {
            this.loading = false;
          });
        },}
```

esto es un modulo actions.js que me recibe el formulario con los datos del index.vue para enviar a la funcion correspondiente del controller, hasta aqui todo bien, puse el console.log para corroborar que se estaban recibiendo los datos del vue y si los recibe:

```
export const fetchContracts = ({ commit }, payload) => {
        console.log(payload);
        return axios
            .get(window.urls.contract.index, payload)
            .then(response => {
                commit("setContracts", response.data);
                return Promise.resolve();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return Promise.reject(error);
            });
    };
```

esta es la funcion del controlador que recibe los datos del formulario del actions.js y realiza la busqueda a partir de los datos recibidos:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $name       = $request->firstname;
        $lastname   = $request->lastname;
        $cellphone  = $request->cellphone;
        $domicile   = $request->domicile;
        $cdcontract = $request->cdcontract;

        $contracts = Contract::join('affiliates', 'affiliates.contract_id', '=', 'contracts.id')
                    ->where('affiliates.first_name', 'like','%'. $name .'%')
                    ->where('affiliates.last_name', 'like','%'. $lastname .'%')
                    ->where('contracts.cellphone', 'like','%'. $cellphone .'%')
                    ->where('contracts.domicile', 'like','%'. $domicile .'%')
                    ->where('contracts.id', 'like','%'. $cdcontract .'%')
                    ->get();

      return $contracts->map(function ($contract) {
            return [
                'id' => $contract->id,
                'number' => $contract->full_number,
                'holder_last_name' => $contract->holder->last_name,
                'holder_first_name' => $contract->holder->first_name,
                'domicile' => $contract->domicile,
                'phone' => $contract->phone,
                'cellphone' => $contract->cellphone,
                'branch' => $contract->branch->name,
                'current_fee' => $contract->current_fee,
            ];
        })->toArray();
}
```

la funcion me trae todos los registros, deberia traerme solo registros que coincidan con uno o mas datos, que estoy haciendo mal?